# Prove that $\cos{2\alpha}+\cos{4\alpha}+\cdots+\cos{2n\alpha} = \frac{\sin(n+1)\alpha \cos{n \alpha}}{\sin{\alpha}}-1$

Tags: trigonometry

I was doing a trigonometry problem and it claimed that $$\cos{2\alpha}+\cos{4\alpha}+\cdots+\cos{2n\alpha} = \dfrac{\sin(n+1)\alpha \cos{n \alpha}}{\sin{\alpha}}-1$$
without proof. Is this supposed to be an obvious result or does it require work to prove it?

Comment: More general question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: $2\sin \alpha \cdot \cos(2k\alpha)= \sin((2k+1)\alpha)-\sin((2k-1)\alpha)\Rightarrow$

$$ \begin{align*} \sum_{k=1}^n \cos(2k\alpha) &=\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n 2\sin\alpha\cdot \cos (2k\alpha)}{2\sin\alpha} \\
\\
&=\frac{ \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sin((2k+1)\alpha)-\sin((2k-1)\alpha)\right)}{2\sin \alpha} \\
\\
&=\dfrac{\sin((2n+1)\alpha)-\sin\alpha}{2\sin \alpha} \\
\\
&=... \end{align*} $$

Comment: I suspect many Readers would benefit from an additional note that this hint allows us to pass to a [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).